# Code execution speed is slower and slower in time

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my project I need to see sensors data in textarea window
and after some time to save those data in txt file.
I use this code :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
`
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>


  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var updateInterval = 50;
    var updateChart = function(count) {
      count = count || 1;

      Val1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      Val2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
      Val3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);

      $(document).ready(function() {
        var $textarea = $('textarea');
        $textarea.scrollTop($textarea[0].scrollHeight);
      });
      var d = new Date();
      $("#output").append(document.createTextNode(d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds() + " - , " + Val1 + ", " + Val2 + ", " + Val3 + "\n"));
    }
    setInterval(function() {
      updateChart()
    }, updateInterval);

    function download(filename, text) {
      var pom = document.createElement('a');
      pom.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
      pom.setAttribute('download', filename);

      pom.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(pom);

      pom.click();

      document.body.removeChild(pom);

    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <form onsubmit="download(this['name'].value, this['text'].value)">
    Filename: <input type="text" name="name" value="                  .txt">
    <textarea id='output' cols="40" rows="10" name="text" style="border:solid 2px blue;">
  Time  ,Val1, Val2, Val3

</textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="SAVE">
  </form>

</body>

</html>`
```

The problem is in the fact: my code execution speed is slower and slower if time
between start and file saving moment is longer !
If I use 20 samples/sec this amount of slowdown is not acceptable.
Is it possible to get faster code and much less dependent of time (txt file size) ?

Comment: You really don't want to be adding a document `ready` handler every time you call `updateChart`

Comment: You should really only need to wrap the `setInterval` call, ie `jQuery(function($) { setInterval(updateChart, updateInterval) })`

Comment: @Phil, yes,it helps but the slowdown persist ( two times slower execution ) for file of modest size of 200 K (or about 20 minutes of recording sensor data).  Still, I do not understand the root of the problem and how to find more efficient code to get a possibility to record data during 1 hour and with minimal slowdown.